# Where does CPAN install Perl modules in OS X?

Tags: perl, macos, cpan

Just curious where CPAN installs all the Perl modules by default in OS X.

Comment: Which Perl distribution are you refering to? The one delivred with the OS?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Ask it!

```
iains-imac:~ bigiain$ perl -e 'print join("\n",@INC)'
/Library/Perl/Updates/5.10.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level
/Library/Perl/Updates/5.10.0
/System/Library/Perl/5.10.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level
/System/Library/Perl/5.10.0
/Library/Perl/5.10.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level
/Library/Perl/5.10.0
/Network/Library/Perl/5.10.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level
/Network/Library/Perl/5.10.0
/Network/Library/Perl
/System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.10.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level
/System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.10.
```

(That's a bog-stock 10.6.3 installation)

Comment: @bigian Awesome : using Perl to answer a Perl question. Thanks.

Comment: perl -V also works. Why didn't I think of that earlier. Oh, well, now it's documented here for the benefit of everyone. ;-

Answer (score 3):

Besides system defaults, you may have configured your CPAN client to install the modules somewhere else. So have a look to your config:

```
$ cpan
cpan> o conf makepl_arg
cpan> o conf make_arg
cpan> o conf make_install_arg
cpan> o conf mbuildpl_arg
cpan> o conf mbuild_arg
cpan> o conf mbuild_install_arg
cpan> exit
```